# Request admin privileges during un-installation

Tags: inno-setup

I'm writing some values to HKLM during the installation of my application.

I'm using the PrivilegesRequired=admin flag in my installer, so during the installation, writing to the registry works fine.

However, when I un-install my application, Inno Setup doesn't request admin privileges, so my call to RegDeleteKeyIncludingSubkeys fails.

I would like to ask if it's possible to make it so that Inno Setup requires admin privileges at un-installation as well.

Thank you very much.

Edit: I've read that the uninstaller should contain this information, but for me, it doesn't. I don't even remember how I created the uninstaller...

Comment: The uninstaller requests Administrator privileges. Show us its log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I haven't figured out how to use /log when I un-install from the Programs & Features->Uninstall dialog. When I use the unins000.exe, I does request admin privileges and everything works fine, but when I uninstall using the Program & Features->Uninstall dialog, it doesn't. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself:

I forgot to sign the uninstaller.
The Windows Programs & Features uninstaller requires that uninstaller have to be signed.

Once I signed the uninstaller, everything would work as expected.